# Unable to copy bak file to container

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-compose

I would like to copy db.bak to mounted volume_backup in order to run restore query basically. But it seems the file cannot be copied even though there message is shown up  `CACHED [2/2] COPY db.bak /var/opt/mssql/backup/`

[image]

Unluckily, the server run but no db.bak file found

```
Msg 3201, Level 16, State 2, Server 3039ef6f2621, Line 1
myssql_1  | Cannot open backup device '/var/opt/mssql/backup/db.bak'. Operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).
myssql_1  | Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Server 3039ef6f2621, Line 1
myssql_1  | RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

Here is my folder structure:

```
|docker-compose.yml
|SqlV1
   |db.bak
   |Dockerfile
|volume_backup
   |[Expected db.bak would be here]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  myssql:
    build: ./SqlV1
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '1433:1433'
    volumes:
      - ./volume_backup:/var/opt/mssql/backup
    networks:
      - data-pipeline

volumes:
  db_data:

networks:
  data-pipeline:
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
ENV MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Abc@123456

USER root
COPY db.bak /var/opt/mssql/backup/

CMD /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd \
   -S localhost -U 'sa' -P $MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD \
   -Q 'RESTORE DATABASE Lion FROM DISK = "/var/opt/mssql/backup/db.bak" WITH MOVE "SRLM" TO "/var/opt/mssql/data/SRLM.mdf", MOVE "SRLM_Log" TO "/var/opt/mssql/data/SRLM.ldf"' & /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
```

If I manually copy to `volume_backup`, it worked fine. I just wonder that why this COPY seems doing nothing?

Comment: Are you sure it's the `/var/opt/mssql/backup/` you're expecting? Seems like the compose file is creating an overriding mount point, `volumes: - ./volume_backup:/var/opt/mssql/backup`. Have you tried to copy the `db.bak` file into the host's `./volume_backup` instead?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I am sure `/var/opt/mssql/backup/` because I have manually copied `db.bak` to the mounted `volume_backup` before running so it worked fine. I have also tried `COPY db.bak ./volume_backup` in Dockerfile but not working too.

Comment: Open a CLI to your running container and execute `ls -la /var/opt/mssql/backup/`. It will only show the files and folders that currently exist in your host's `./volume_backup` folder because that mount point overrides what was previously created in the image by your `Dockerfile`.

Comment: I see, I have tried `COPY db.bak /var/opt/mssql/backup/` and commented out volume definition in Dockerfile then it worked perfectly. So the issue here is the mount point overrides previously created. I just thought that it would restore db, containerized as running image, then mount the folder and list out db.bak in volume_backup

Comment: If it were me I'd remove the `COPY` from the `Dockerfile` and leave the mountpoint in the compose - with the `db.bak` file residing in the `./volume_backup` folder. This gives you two benefits: 1) the image file is smaller, and 2) the newly instantiated containers will restore the current `db.bak` file, i.e.: you don't have to build a new image for each and every changed database backup, just overwrite the `./volume_backup/db.bak` file and start a new container.

Comment: I got your idea, thank you very much.

Comment: You mount a volume on `/var/opt/mssql/backup` which hides any files in that location in the image and replaces them with the mounted directory.

Comment: Yes @HansKilian, I was confused about the volume, can you correct me why it is replaced even if folder `volume_backup` does not exist yet?

Comment: if the to be bound `$(pwd)/volume_backup` local directory does not exist, docker will try to create it at container start and then mount it on the container. If this fails the container will not start. Hence, if it succeeds, your local folder will be empty.

Comment: Thank you @Zeitounator I'm clear now. So the mounting procedure executed after my `COPY` and before final `CMD` which causes overridden result because `CMD` start later than container start.